# Is there any way to optimize this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

i have two  tables called `hg_questions` and `hg_tags` related with `hg_question_tag` which has the following structure:

```
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| qid     | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tagid   | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| tagname | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

i have only one index on this table for `tagid` column, the following query runs so slow, since i have exactly `59440` rows for tag number `464` (so many questions in this tag)

```
SELECT hg_questions.qid,
hg_questions.question,
hg_questions.points,
hg_questions.reward,
hg_questions.answerscount,
hg_questions.created_at,
hg_questions.sections,
hg_questions.answered,
hg_questions.user_id
FROM hg_questions
INNER JOIN hg_question_tag ON hg_question_tag.qid = hg_questions.qid
WHERE hg_question_tag.tagid = 464
ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 15
OFFSET 0;
```

when running explain on this query i get:

```
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                              | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | hg_question_tag | ref    | tagid         | tagid   | 9       | const                            | 59440 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | hg_questions    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | ejaaba_bilal.hg_question_tag.qid |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

any ideas how i can optimize this query? or there is a way to get it work faster.

---

1. `hg_questions` has an index on `points` column
2. removed `order by points` makes it work faster like 80%

Comment: can you post the hg_questions and hg_tags table also, just so we can be sure what they look like?

Comment: alright, i'll post it now.

Comment: @Bilal, try creating an index on points.

Comment: @Vlad yes i have an index on points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query, simplified to some extent:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM hg_questions q INNER JOIN
     hg_question_tag qt
     ON qt.qid = q.qid
WHERE qt.tagid = 464
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0;
```

You are doing both a `join` and an `order by`.  To optimize this query, try putting an index on `hg_question_tag(tagid, qid)`.  This will work if not many questions have the tag.

If many questions have the tag, it might be better to go through the questions and choose the appropriate ones.  Try rewriting the query as:

```
select q.*
from hg_questions q
where exists (select 1 from hg_question_tag qt where qt.qid = q.qid and qt.tagid = 464)
order by points desc
limit 15 offset 0;
```

Keep the above index and put another index on `hg_questions(points, qid)`.

Comment: By "not work" I assume that most methods had similar performance to your original query?

Comment: your solution gave me a lot worst performance, it turns out that querying tags only (without joining questions) and fetching related questions in a loop gave better performance. http://www.ejaaba.com/label/464

Comment: @Bilal . . . I assume that is true even after the stated indexes were created.

Comment: yes, i created all the indices and used the query you gave, the mysql server gone away